# Создание View/Activity по XML-разметке

Tags: android, xml, view, android-view

Передо мой стоит задача - необходимо создавать экран activity по данным с сервера.
На данный момент, я в onCreate стучусь на сервер и получаю шрифты, бекграунды, цвета и прочую мелочь.

И мне стало интересно: можно ли сформировать на сервере xml-строку и использовать вместо

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity);
```

что-то такое

```
setContentView(View.createFromXml("<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Layout> ... </Layout>"));
```

Comment: `LayoutInflayter` "из коробки" не работает с чистым `xml`, только с компилированным. Причина - идентификаторы ресурсов доподлинно известны только на момент сборки и при каждой сборке могут измениться, а в вашем `xml` останутся старые. Но вы можете написать собственный парсер и воссоздать всю вью-иерархию по параметрам из `xml` программно. Когда то здесь уже задавали такой вопрос и там упоминалось что есть готовые решения на гитхабе, поищите.